# List rating changes new list item view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rating, classic

I have created a list, and adding new list items brings up the default "new" view, which is fine. However, after enabling ratings for the list, whenever I add a new list item, it brings up the "classic" view, with no way to change it. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my end and observed the same behavior. It could be due to the lack of support of rating feature for modern list form. Here is a [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/20326732-add-star-rating-for-modern-experience-list) you can vote.

Comment: That's great, thanks Jerry. I will look at forcing the modern view through Power Apps. Cheers.